# get what's inside an object in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
const test = `
{
  "name": "Error",
}

{
  "name": "Signup Success",
  "status": "400",
  "body": {
     "name": {
        "first": "test",
      },
      "roles": [
       "user"
      ],
      "isMale": true,
  }
}
`
```

How can i get what's inside the two objects separately. Like the first object contains `"name": "Error"` and the second object contains :

```
  "name": "Signup Success",
  "status": "400",
  "body": {
     "name": {
        "first": "test",
      },
      "roles": [
       "user"
      ],
      "isMale": true,
  }
```

Comment: You would have to parse it yourself. `JSON.parse` only works for JSON, but that string is not JSON.

Comment: Where is the string coming from ? to decode JSON, you cannot have leftover commans, as in `"isMale": true,`

Comment: I retreive it from a file, the content is written as a doc format

Comment: It's hard to say without a separator between an object-string and another object-string. You could build a parser, but it's not easy

Comment: `split("\r\n\r\n")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String#replace to get rid of trailing `,` (like: `"name": {"first": "test",}` after "test")

`.replace(/,(\n*\s*)(})/g, "$2")`

Then use String#split by targeting the space between `}` and `{` (notice Regex `LookBehinds` are not yet implemented everywhere)

`.split(/(?<=})\n+(?={)/)`

Then Array#map to transform each section in an object.

```js
const test = `
{
  "name": "Error",
}

{
  "name": "Signup Success",
  "status": "400",
  "body": {
     "name": {
        "first": "test",
      },
      "roles": [
       "user"
      ],
      "isMale": true,
  }
}
`

const [error, data] = test
.replace(/,(\n*\s*)(})/g, "$2")
.split(/(?<=})\n+(?={)/)
.map(raw=>JSON.parse(raw));

console.log(error, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just in the format you've posted you may just `split` it with `\n\n` as separator:

```
let objects = test.split("\n\n")
```

And if resulting code is valid JSON (in example it's not valid) you may parse it:

```
let parsed = objects.map(JSON.parse)
```

A valid JSON would be:

```
const test = `
{
    "name": "Error"
}

{
    "name": "Signup Success",
    "status": "400",
    "body": {
        "name": {
            "first": "test"
        },
        "roles": [
            "user"
        ],
        "isMale": true
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a parser:

```js
const test = `
{
  "name": "Error",
}

{
  "name": "Signup Success",
  "status": "400",
  "body": {
     "name": {
        "first": "test",
      },
      "roles": [
       "user"
      ],
      "isMale": true,
  }
}
`;

const addCommas = str => {
  const charactersArray = Array.from(str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
  charactersArray.reduce((acc, curr, index, self) => {
    if (curr === '{') acc++;
    if (curr === '}') acc--;
    if (acc === 0 && curr === '}') self[index] = '},';
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  return charactersArray.join('').replace(/,\}/g, '}').replace(/,$/, '');
};

const parsedObject = JSON.parse('['+addCommas(test)+']');

parsedObject.forEach((el, i) => {
  console.log(`Element ${i+1} name: ${el.name}`);
});
```

This is 100% safe because also strings lile `"}{"` don't cause problems

Comment: "*This is 100% safe*" - far from it. It breaks completely or changes the content for different strings, e.g. `{"name": "}{"}` or `{"name": "\"}{"}`.